# How to disable the SDMMC interface in STM32

Tags: stm32, hal

I am using STM32L476(with SW4STM32 & STM32CubeMX) for a low power application. I have interfaced SD card through SDMMC interface (with FatFs ) of the micro-controller. This interface is consuming current in the range of 1mA. So i am planning to disable the SDMMC interface, whenever it is not needed. I didn't find any APIs in the HAL documentation to disable it.How to disable the SDMMC interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDMMC is on the APB2 bus, you can disable the clock to the peripheral by setting bit 10 of the `RCC_APB2ENR` to 0, this is documented on page 259 of the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00083560.pdf) for that processor.

The code you need is something along the lines of the following, depending on the library you're using.

```
RCC->APB2ENR &= ~RCC_APB2ENR_SDMMCEN;
```

To turn it back on again, you need to do the opposite, set that bit to 1

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SDMMCEN;
```

It is quite possible there is a function in the HAL which does this for you, but someone who uses the library and is familiar with it will have to help with that.